# symmetric group of equilateral triangle?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We can represent rotations of a equilateral triangle by matrices . Can we represent flips of a equilateral triangle by matrices ??

Comment: Here's one:  $\left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: Yes, this is something of a standard topic in *group representation theory*.  There is a subgroup of $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrices which is isomorphic to $S_3$, the symmetry group of an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  Giving "one" of the matrices doesn't mean a lot in isolation.  While that matrix could belong to a matrix group that represents the symmetry group of an equilateral triangle, some limitations on coordinates for the triangle coordinates will be imposed.

Comment: but we cannot consider this matrices form a group, because if we multiply any 2 flip matrices we cannot get rotation matrix . but for triangle combination of flips is equivalent to rotation . @ J. W. Tanner

Answer (score 0):

You can represent any lineal transformation with matrices, and flips are linear (assuming the center of the triangle is the origin).

Please note flips are usually called reflections.

Comment: Can the set of all matrices those represents reflections and rotations form a group, ??

Comment: Yes they do, it is called the orthogonal group. (Although in higher dimensions the orthogonal group has more stuff, like inversion around a point).

Comment: can u give an example of a reflection matrix?? i tried a lot but i don't get a reflection matrix which can form group with rotation matrices

Comment: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ is an example of one, it is a left-right reflection. because it sends vector $(1,0)$ to vector $(-1,0)$

Comment: actually rotation of an equilateral triangle has 3 states  can be represent as   (1 0  0 ) , ( 0  1   0 ) , (0  0  1)  , how can you act this 2 by 2 reflection matrix on that states ?

Comment: You can calculate the matrix for a reflection through any given line that passes through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use @J.W.Tanner's example of a reflection matrix, you need to position the vertices of the equilateral triangle accordingly.

Let the set of three vertices be $\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 3/2 \\ -1/2 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt 3/2 \\ -1/2 \end{bmatrix}\}$.  Then the matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ acts as reflection in the $y$-axis (changing the sign of the $x$ coordinate).  But we need six matrices to have a group of order six like the symmetry group of the equilateral triangle.

Note that the matrix that [rotates counterclockwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) about the origin by $2\pi/3$ (or $120^\circ$) is:

$$R=\begin{pmatrix} \cos (2\pi/3) & -\sin (2\pi/3) \\ \sin (2\pi/3) & \cos (2\pi/3 )\end{pmatrix}$$

This last matrix has multiplicative order three, $R^3 = I$, while a reflection matrix such as $M$ has multiplicative order two.  Together the matrices $M$ and $R$ generate a group isomorphic to $S_3$, the symmetry group of the equilateral triangle.

In this representation of the symmetric group $S_3$ (every permutation of vertices corresponds to a placement of the equilateral triangle back onto itself) the rotations are $I,R,$ and $R^2$.  The other three group elements are reflections, $M, MR,$ and $RM$.  So both rotations and reflections can be realized as matrix transformations of the plane $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: is this is the representation of symmetric group of a triangle?

Comment: I've given you two of the six matrices that make up a finite subgroup of (orthogonal) $2\times 2$ matrices, so yes that is commonly called a *group representation* of the symmetric group of an equilateral triangle.  If you write out all six possible matrices, $I,R,R^2,M,MR,RM$, you can verify how they act on the three points I gave as the vertices, i.e. they cause a permutation of the three vertices in all possible ways.